# MySql Procedure with multiple counts and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have been creating an app for a charity that allows families to sign up to receive gifts around the holiday season.  The db organization has multiple tables.  These tables (and their schema/create statements) are listed below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ValidDates(
  chosenYear YEAR PRIMARY KEY, 
  startDate DATE NOT NULL,
  endDate DATE NOT NULL,
  maxReservationsPerDay INTEGER default 50, 
  CONSTRAINT chkDates CHECK(startDate < endDate)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Families(
  fID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  signature BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
  reservationDate DATE NOT NULL,
  signatureTS TIMESTAMP,
  createdTS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  createdBy INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (createdBy) REFERENCES Employees(eID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FamilyMembers(
  fmID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  lName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  age INTEGER NOT NULL,
  sex BIT(1) NOT NULL, 
  ssNum VARCHAR(9) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  recievedBig BIT(1) DEFAULT 0,
  recievedNormal BIT(1) DEFAULT 0,
  recievedStocking BIT(1) DEFAULT 0,
  famID INTEGER,
  INDEX fIndex (famID), 
  FOREIGN KEY (famID) REFERENCES Families(fID)  ON DELETE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I would like to write **one** query (stored procedure) that will go through and for each date, select the date, number of families being served on that date, and the total number of family members being served on that date. For example, it should return that on Dec 12 2018, there are a total of 5 families with reservations and among these families, they have 13 family members in total (family with id 1 has 5 members, family with id 2 has 1 member, family id 3 has 1 member, id 4 has 4 member, and family 5 has 2 members).  It should do this for all the dates.  Thank you for the help.

Note: these values will be placed into a Dictionary< DateTime, tuple< int, int >> in c# (where the key is the date, and the first int is the number of families and the second int is the number of members in those families) and used for reporting functionality.

Comment: How do you define *kid*? Are there families without kids?

Comment: You know that this `CONSTRAINT chkDates CHECK(startDate < endDate)` doesn't work in MySQL right? "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines" ->  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: @dnoeth any usage of the word "kid" refers to a record in the family members table.  I have revised my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the expected result (without using the `ValidDates` table):

```
select reservationDate
  ,count(distinct fmID) as #_of_families
  ,count(*) as #_of_familiy_members
from Families as f
join FamilyMembers as fm
  on f.fID = fm.famID
group by reservationDate
```